# Joining table to feature class using ArcGIS with Delimiter?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, delimiter

I have a table of attributes that correspond to different cities in my state in an excel file that I am trying to join to a polygon feature class, based on the city name.

After executing the join, when I go to symbolize based on these new attributes, this is what I see under the symbology tab:

[image: Layer properties]

I cannot list the unique categorical values; it looks like a delimiter issue where several columns are somehow being combined, but there are no extraneous commas, punctuation marks, etc. in the table.  The table originated in Excel; I saved as a .csv then used the 'Table to Table' tool to import it into ArcGIS as a table in a file geodatabase.

Where in the join process did I go wrong?

Comment: Have you tried "Excel to Table' under Conversion Tools?

Answer (score 4):

You could keep what you have and use the split() python function to get back your 3 different values in 3 different columns.

Create 3 fields :

- For the first field, a string field, named for example NAME, fill it in with the field calculator in Python mode and enter the following code : !CITY!.split(',')[0]
- For the second field, a integer field, named for example NUMBER1, fill  it in with the field calculator in Python mode and enter the following code : !CITY!.split(',')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Sy5.jpg)
- For the third field, a integer field,  named for example NUMBER2, fill  it in with the field calculator in Python mode and enter the following code : !CITY!.split(',')[2]

Example below :

[image]